# TM that it's Language is only 10 words

Tags: turing-machines

I was wondering how to create a TM that it's $L(M) = 10$, I think it would be recognizable, but I need help building that TM.
so far I have this pseudocode:
$$
N:" ∀x∈sigma^*
$$
$run$ $N$ $on$ $x$
if N acc $then$ $i=i+1$
if i==11 then $stop$

please help solve this

Comment: Can you explain your notation? Do you mean the language has only one member, "10"? I guess the alphabet is {0,1}, am I right? If so, then how is "+" defined?

Comment: You haven't defined $M$ yet.

Comment: that's because I'm wondering if it's possible to do a "int counter" like in programming and how